# How do i use input variables to locate ids with UPDATE in sqlite3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to make a contacts list manageable by user input. Program asks what the user wants to do, either to add a new contact, edit a contact, delete a contact or show a list of contacts, if the user wants to edit contacts then he's asked for the id of the contact he wants to change, and then the row he wants to change(name, lastname or number).. What i don't know is, how do i go into using the sql UPDATE command together with that id the user gave, and then how do i use the new name, or last name or number given by the user with the same command, update? So that i the user can actually pick which contact to edit and what parameter to edit from the menu.

Here's my code.

```
import sqlite3

asd = True
while asd:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('contactsdb.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts''')
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE contacts
                  (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Nombre TEXT, Apellido TEXT, Numero de celular INTEGER)''')

    # def agregarconbg():
    #     global nombre
    #     global apellido
    #     global numero

    def agregarcon():
        nombre = input("Add name")
        apellido = input("Add lastname")
        numero = input("Add number")
        # c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (nombre, apellido, numero) VALUES(?,?,?);",(nombre,apellido,numero))
        conn.commit()

    def editnom():
        nuevonom = input("Add new name")
        ###################################################
        ###################################################
        #########What do i do around here?!################
        c.execute("UPDATE contacts set nombre where ID=1",(nuevonom))
        conn.commit
    # def editap():
    #
    # def editnum():

    def editarcon():
        print ("What id do you want to change?")
        cambiar = input("Introduce the id you want to change:")
        print("""What do you want to change
        1 - Name
        2 - Lastname
        3 - Number""")
        cambiarpar = int(input("Seleccion:"))
        if cambiarpar == 1:
            editnom()
        elif cambiarpar == 2:
            editap()
        elif cambiarpar == 3:
            editnum()
        else:
            print("Wrong INPUT")
        # c = conn.cursor()


    #def borrarcon():
    #    c = conn.cursor()
    def printsql():
        # c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id')
        listT = ["ID","Nombre:","Apellido:","Numero:"]
        k = 0
        for i in c:
            print("\n")
            for j in i:
                print (listT[k])
                print(j)
                if k < 3: k+=1
                else: k = 0
    conn.commit()

    print('Agenda de contactos')
    print('''Que deseas hacer?
    1 - Add a contact
    2 - Edit a contact
    3 - Delete a contact
    4 - Show contacts''')

    seleccion = int(input("Seleccion:"))

    if seleccion == 1:
        agregarcon()
    elif seleccion == 2:
        editarcon()
        conn.commit()
    elif seleccion == 3:
        borrarcon()
        conn.commit
    elif seleccion == 4:
        printsql()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Cambiar(ID) through as a parameter to editnom() and use that as part of the update statement, plus use nombre = variable to actually update the record

[See this page for SQLite3 UPDATE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm)

[See this for how to pass variables through to functions in Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm)

`def editnom(cambiar):
        nuevonom = input("Add new name")
        ###################################################
        ###################################################
        #########What do i do around here?!################
        c.execute("UPDATE contacts set nombre = ? where ID=?",(nuevonom,cambiar))
        conn.commit`

`if cambiarpar == 1:
            editnom(cambiar)`